# timepicker adjust minute step

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used http://jonthornton.github.com/jquery-timepicker/ timepicker. ITs half hour by half hour. I want to make a timepicker by 1 minute. I write script in my php file. But nothing happened.

Here is my script code:

```
$(function() {
        $('#xyz').timepicker({ 
        'timeFormat': 'H:i',
        defaultTime: 'current',
        minuteStep: 1,
        disableFocus: true,
        template: 'dropdown'});

        });
```

What should I do?

Comment: The [documentation](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#timepicker-plugin-for-jquery) clearly states to use `step: 1`, but you've used `minuteStep: 1`... RTM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#xyz').timepicker({ 
    'timeFormat': 'H:i',
    defaultTime: 'current',
    step: 1,
    disableFocus: true,
    template: 'dropdown'});

    });
```